# MongoDB Compass Community: $match in aggregation gives “Expected ”[“ or AggregationStage but ”{“ found.”

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I'm using MongoDB Compass Community version 1.17.0.
While trying to use `$match` as the first step, it's giving me this message

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `new` in front of `Date` from your query.

Use this

```
{
  utcDate: { $gt : Date("2019-04-01") }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with removing `new`

```
{
 utcDate:{$gt:Date("2019-04-01")}
}
```